# Solving approach a Perm Gen out of memory memory issue

Tags: java, out-of-memory, permgen

**Please read it completely before marking it duplicate.**

I have gone through many blogs/post here and on google in order to find a concrete way to resolve the perm gen OOM issue; but none of them has solved the issue so far. Here is the my use-case:

1. I have a tomcat server on which many individual project *.war files are deployed.
2. The perm gen issue was not a problem initially and we kept on adding more modules.
3. Recently we faced Perm Gen - OOM issue and it was successfully resolved by increasing perm gen memory in JVM parameter.
4. We kept on adding more modules and then one fine day again encountered this issue.
5. As a temporary solution, we keep on re-starting our server and the issue remain silent for a week or so.

**Approach towards permanent solution:**

- The famous approach to increase perm gen in JVM parameter is not an option anymore.
- I understand that this could be a code issue, which is causing perm gen memory leak. But reviewing the huge codebase is almost impossible.

**Your help needed**:

> Is there a free tool or quick way (or tips) to figure out a bad code
> here?

**One observation in our code module:**

- I have observed that in each of the module *war, there is 80% common jar used, but all of them is bundled individually into each of the war.

**My analysis here (I may be wrong)**

- The tomcat server must be using individual app-classloader for each of the modules war.
- So, even though two same classes from a jar (say same abcd.jar located into different war) gets loaded in perm gen area; they would not be visible to each other (due to java security model).
- In short for each of the app, many copies of a class may be getting loaded (which, otherwise could be made common).

**Your help needed**:

> Is the above analysis holds true?
>
> If we move the common jars into some common lib path and include that path into tomcat shared lib configuration, would it help? My target is only one copy of class loaded into perm gen area.

**At last** - What other way I should think about?

Comment: Is using other jvm an option? I heard IBM JVM does not have permgen.  It may be true for Jrockit (now under Oracle) jvm.

Comment: YourKit has good detector for permgen leak. Give a try (couple of days eval is free) : http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/class_loaders.jsp

Comment: Thanks Jayan, I do not have an option to change JVM. I would try using yourkit.

Comment: You wrote that you are getting the problems not directly, but after maybe a week. Do you redeploy during that time or is the server running without redeployment? In 1st case simply start your server after redeployment and you'll probably be fine. In 2nd case you probably have a memory leak related to loading classes, have a look at dynamic class generation (e.g. web service wrappers, xPath evaluations and stuff like that.

Comment: Did you try tomcat's inbuilt leak detection? http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

Comment: @Matthias, after each module is deployed or re-deployed on the server, the server is re-started. So, looks like 2nd issue. Do you think my approach of segregating common jar may resolve the issue?

Comment: @Hari shankar. Thanks Hari, I would look into this, if this can help me.

Comment: @gyan I do not think that will solve the problem. It would reduce gen space usage sureley (on the expense of breaking encapsulation of your war-files). But your issue seems to be related to a component with a memory leak (with perm gen almost always some dynamic classes which are created on the fly)

Comment: @Matthias, thanks for the tip. Just one thing, I do not have any xPath evaluators; do have webservice call and using 3rd party open source component jar. Problem is that how may I control the memory leak by 3rd party jars? In the above approach, I am not breaking war file encapsulation; it would be like that the war files would need additional jars in the server classpath (which otherwise would have laded up into war\lib folder). It is same as like servlets.jar provided by the tomcat container for which we never bother to include in the war\lib folder.

Comment: @gyan What I meant by that is that you now force all your wars to load the same classes from those libs (or have different versions of those libs in that folder). Also you might experience side effects from static fields of those classes, since they are now scoped over the whole tomcat, not restricted to the war (by class loader magic). As a sidenote. A usually good tool for investigation perm gen leaks is visual vm. Just do different actions to your tomcat and check in visual vm if new classes get loaded every time you do an request. 1st time is normal, after 2nd time should not happen ;)

Comment: Thanks Matthias for all the insight. I am still in POC phase for my approach, I would definitely keep an watch on the side-effects and also see if Visual-vm could help me.